# Forcing `appcompat-v7:24.0.3` is giving an error message

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am already using `appcompat-v7:24.0.3` in my project, but when i use it with force, it gives me following error message

> Error:(73, 19) Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.3 Install Repository and sync project

I have tried to click on Install Repository, but its already installed. So it does nothing on click. I am using following `resolutionStrategy`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
       /* resolutionStrategy.failOnVersionConflict()*/
        force 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
        force 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.3'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.3'
    }
}
```

If i go to older version, and use these, it does not give any error message.

```
    force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    force 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
```

and if i remove force and only use compile, it does not give any error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error:(73, 19) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.3 Install Repository and sync project

It happens because `appcompat-v7:24.0.3` **doesn't exist.**

You can the [official history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html):

Revision archive:

```
25.1.1
25.1.0
25.0.1
25.0.0
24.2.1
24.2.0
24.1.1
24.1.0
24.0.0
23.4.0
23.3.0
```

Also use the same level of support libraries, for example:

```
   force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try that, but I don't know why its working fine when i don't use force, and just use `compile` keyword